# In AWS Lambda 403 ERROR: The request could not be satisfied

Tags: aws-lambda

I was pushing lambda function in AWS Lambda and getting below error.

Could not find the required '.deps.json'.  This file should be present at the root of the deployment package.: LambdaException

Comment: Do you have the `deps.json` file in your upload to the Lambda console? And can I assume you are using .NET Core?

Comment: Yes, I have deps.json file and I am using .Net core.

Comment: And the file is in the root of your zip directory? Not inside a subfolder

Comment: yes, this file is in root directory

Comment: @PrashantBamania, did you ever find a solution to this? I am having what seems to be the same issue. `[Assembly].deps.json` is in the root folder but I receive this error specifying the exact file name that exists.